# Generic Type In Objective C

Tags: objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I have several types os root view controller that I want to instantiate one at a time (once per function call). I want to create a property and assign it to this newly created viewcontroller. The problem obviously is that this property will have to be of a specific type dependent on the viewcontroller it is instantiating...

Is there a way to create a generic pointer to overcome this....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats what `id` is in Objective-C, a untyped Objective-C object pointer.

```
id test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

etc

Comment: I wouldn't really call it "dynamically typed", only that it's a type that represents any object.

Comment: Abizern: Actually, no he doesn't. An 'id' could refer to any object, including objects that do not derive from NSObject but from some other custom implementation of NSObject or whatever.  It's more or less the ObjC equivalent of (void*).

Comment: `id` is not equivalent to `NSObject*`

Comment: Fair enough - my idiocy has been deleted ;)

Comment: I;ve done this, but it causes an awful lot of "Request for member....not a structure or union"

Comment: @user: Did you write id* by mistake?

Answer (score 8):

There is indeed a generic pointer type; it is `id`:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Which is defined in [objc.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/objc.h), part of the [runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/). You can assign any object to a pointer of type `id`:

```
id myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
id myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
id myNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
```

It's also possible, when programming in Cocoa, to use `NSObject *` as a sort of generic pointer; since it is the primary root class, nearly every object inherits from it. There's not much gained from doing that, however (in fact, you'll start getting "May not respond to" compiler warnings), and it's not idiomatic.

In general, it is best to type your variables as specifically as possible. In this case, since all the objects will be some kind of view controller, I would recommend using `UIViewController *` as the variable type. Then any object which inherits from `UIViewController` can be assigned to that pointer, and you still allow the compiler to do type checking.