# iPhone Application Error Problem

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

Bear with me on this one.

I have an iphone application. It is a questionnaire application. There are several types of question, some have a slider, some have text input etc.  I have developed a view controller for each type of question.

Two example types of question controllers are: TextInputQuestionViewController and SliderQuestionViewController.

I have a rootViewcontroller named QuestionnaireViewController.  This is defined as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JSONKit.h";
#import "dbConnector.h"
#import "SliderQuestionViewController.h";
#import "TextInputQuestionViewController.h";
#import "MainMenuProtocol.h";

@interface QuestionnaireViewController : UIViewController {
    NSDictionary* questions;
    NSMutableArray* questionArray;
    NSMutableArray* answerArray;
    dbConnector* db;
    SliderQuestionViewController* currQ; //need to create a generic var
    TextInputQuestionViewController* currQ;
    NSInteger currQNum; 
    NSString* qaTitle;
    NSString* secId;
    id<MainMenuProtocol>delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* questions;   
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* questionArray;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* answerArray;
@property(nonatomic, retain) dbConnector* db;
@property(nonatomic, retain) SliderQuestionViewController* currQ;
@property(nonatomic, retain) TextInputQuestionViewController* currTI;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger currQNum;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* qaTitle;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* secId;
@property(nonatomic, retain) id <MainMenuProtocol> delegate;

-(void) setQuestions;
-(void) startQuestion:(NSInteger)index isLast:(BOOL)last;
-(void) loadQuestions;
-(void) initialise;
-(void) finishQuestionnaire:(id)sender;
-(void) switchViews:(id)sender;


@end



#import "QuestionnaireViewController.h"
#import "dbConnector.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "JSONKit.h";
#import "Answer.h";


@implementation QuestionnaireViewController
@synthesize questions, questionArray, db, currQ, currQNum, answerArray, qaTitle, secId, delegate;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self initialise];
    answerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = qaTitle; //set to whatever section is
}

-(void) initialise {
    currQNum = 0;
    [self loadQuestions];
    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(switchViews:)];          
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
}

-(void) loadQuestions {
    db = [[dbConnector alloc]init];
    //code to initialise view
    [db getQuestions:secId from:@"http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_questions.php" respondToDelegate:self]; 
}

//called when questions finished loading
//stores dictionary of questions
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *qs = [json objectFromJSONString]; 
    self.questions = qs;
    [json release]; 
    [qs release];
    [self setQuestions];
}


//assigns JSON to question objects
-(void) setQuestions {
    questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *q in self.questions) {               
        /* Create Question object and populate it */
        id question;
        if([[q objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Slider"]){
            question = [[SliderQuestionViewController alloc]init];  
            //set min max values
        }else if([[q objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Option"]){

        }else if([[q objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"TextInput"]){
            question = [[TextInputQuestionViewController alloc]init];
        }else if([[q objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"ImagePicker"]){

        }else{
            //comments

        }
        //if else to create appropriate view controller - NEED to identify question type

        [question setQuestionId:[q objectForKey:@"questionId"] withTitle:[q objectForKey:@"question"] number:[q objectForKey:@"questionNumber"] section:[q objectForKey:@"sectionId"] questionType: [q objectForKey:@"type"]];
        /* Add it to question (mutable) array */
        [questionArray addObject:question]; 
        [question release];
    }
}

-(void) startQuestion:(NSInteger)index isLast:(BOOL)last{
    //currQ = [[QuestionViewController alloc]init];
    currQ = [questionArray objectAtIndex:index];
    //push currQ onto navigationcontroller stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:currQ animated:YES];
    [currQ addButton:self isLast: last];
}

//pushes new view onto navigation controller stack
-(void) switchViews:(id)sender{ 
    Answer* ans = currQ.question.answer;
    ans.questionId = currQ.question.qId;
    ans.entryId = @"1";//temporary;
    if(currQNum < [questionArray count] - 1){       
        if(currQNum > 0){           
            //if else for different input types
            NSString* qt = currQ.question.qType;
            if([qt isEqualToString:@"Slider"]){
                ans.answer = currQ.sliderLabel.text;
            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"Option"]){               

            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"TextInput"]){
                //NSLog(@"%@", currQ.inputAnswer);
                ans.answer = currQ.inputAnswer.text;
            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"ImagePicker"]){

            }else{

            }                       
            [answerArray addObject: ans];
            [ans release];
        }
        [self startQuestion:currQNum isLast:FALSE];     
        currQNum++;
    }else{
        ans.answer = currQ.sliderLabel.text;
        [answerArray addObject: ans];

        //store data temporarily - section finished     
        [self startQuestion:currQNum isLast:TRUE];              
        currQNum++;
    }
    [ans release];
}

-(void) finishQuestionnaire:(id)sender{
    //go back to main manual
    //if else statement for answers
    NSString* answ = currQ.sliderLabel.text;
    [answerArray addObject: answ];
    [delegate finishedSection:answerArray section:secId];
    [answ release];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.questions = nil;
    self.currQ = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

//hide back button in navigation bar
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [currQ release];
    [db release];
    [questionArray release];
    [questions release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

the problematic lines with the above are in the switchViews function.  I need to make the answer equal to the specific input component in that question view (slider value, text input value).  So I need to make currQ a type that can be instantiated using any view controller.

I therefore need a generic variable to hold the current question. currQ holds the current question, but at the moment is of type SliderQuestionViewController.  I tried to change this to id, but it throws a load of "Request For member...not a structure of union" and also a load of misassigned pointer issues.

Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic Type In Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740873/generic-type-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads like you want a pointer for a `UIViewController`, so just use that as the type. Then you can cast it down to whatever subclass you like later. For example:

```
-(void)myAction:(UIViewController *)vc {
    SpecialViewController *svc = (SpecialViewController *)vc;
    ...
}
```

In your case, declare

```
UIViewController* currQ;
```

and then cast it as needed in the implementation to access the different properties and methods of your two subclasses.

Comment: I did this and it caused loads of Request for...errors like above(in the switchView method) It's as if it is trying to access members in UIViewController instead of my custom view controller... Am I assigining currQ incorrectly (currQ = [questionArray objectAtIndex:index];)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a 'generic' variable, you should be able to use `id`.  Make sure you don't define the type as `id*`, the asterisk should *not* be present.

A better idea, though, is to create a superclass for your question viewcontrollers.  Create a superclass called `QuestionViewController` that inherits from `UIViewController` and have the Slider and TextInput (and any others) inherit from `QuestionViewController`.  Then you can define your variable as:  `QuestionViewController* currQ;`  You can put any common functionality in that superclass as well and eliminate duplication.